# Program menu disappeared

Tags: menu, gtk, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I see the menubar in some applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23562/why-cant-i-see-the-menubar-in-some-applications)

My problem is as follows:

The program menu, the one that has file edit view all that does not display in some programs like

- Audicity
- Play on linux

when i change the theme in the appearance it appears again
i really do not know what is wrong with that or why.

i have ubuntu 10.10 and  running compiz have ubuntu tweak

thanks for all that will answer and all that can not

really thanks dudes.

ubuntu is sure fun

Comment: do you have the appmenu installed?