# Why can't I see the menubar in some applications?

Tags: gnome-panel, menu, appmenu

I don't run gnome-panel normally. Most menubars work correctly. However, with wxMaxima and Audacity, they are not showing. When I start gnome-panel and add an appmenu, I can see the menus again.

Without panel:

[image]

[image]

With panel:

[image]

[image]

I get no relevant errors when I run from a terminal.

Why does this happen and what could I do to fix it? Against which package would I file this if this is a bug?

Comment: For what it's worth, I also do not run gnome-panel (`/desktop/gnome/session/required_components/panel` in GConf is `avant-window-navigator`) and wxMaxima's menu bar is displayed between its title bar and toolbar.

Comment: My `/desktop/gnome/session/required_components/panel` is also `avant-window-navigator`.

Comment: If you've experimented with the application menu in the past, [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18615/program-menu-disappeared/18621#18621) might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now [reported this as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-appmenu/+bug/708854).

The work around is to edit ~/.bashrc by opening your home folder, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and double clicking the file '.bashrc' to open it in the text editor. Add the following line to the file:

```
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
```

That only works for launching the program using the terminal. To fix the menu items, use the method outlined in the answer to [Is it possible to make indicator-appmenu ignore a specific application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6784/is-it-possible-to-make-indicator-appmenu-ignore-a-specific-application/6802#6802).

I eventually got it to work by creating a bash script to run the program with UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0.

```
#!/bin/bash
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
/path/to/executable
```

and then editing the command in the application launcher to:

```
bash /path/to/bash/script
```

Comment: I think `env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /path/to/executable` should also work and looks a little cleaner.