# Ubuntu 18.10, Gedit 3.30.1 disappeared from apps menu

Tags: software-center, icons, gedit, appmenu, 18.10

Upon upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10 something happened to Gedit:

1. Its icon disappeared from my favorites (the only one doing so)
2. It doesn't appear anymore on the apps grid
3. Though it's installed I can't launch it from the Software Center

The only way I can launch it is from the terminal and then I get a pixelized icon which I can't add/pin it to my favorites.

I tried:

1. Removing/purging and re-installing (with Software Center and Terminal)
2. Make a soft link of `/usr/bin/gedit` and pin it but it didn't work
3. In `dconf org.gnome.gedit` (plugins, state, prefs) I didn't find any value or a key concerning this problem
4. saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/23573/690957) workaround but it doesn't solve the UI problem.

I didn't try snap because I prefer it to stick with PPA (I generally use snap for only for "special" app)

EDIT (17/11/18):

1. My file manager is Nemo 3.9.0 and to prevent collisions I've removed Nautilus which comes default with Ubuntu.
2. I use Communitheme and Suru as the applications and icons appearance themes respectively

Any suggestions will be welcomed

Thanks

[image: Software Center screenshot]

[image: Apps grid screenshot]

[image: /usr/lib/gedit screenshot]

[image: Trying to run /usr/bin/gedit screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version you upgraded from but when I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 I thought I had lost gedit as well. It turns out that I didn't. It's not listed as gedit in the application menu, it's listed as "Text Editor".

Comment: Nope. That's trivial. In the app menu it search's both title and description so if you write "text editor" you'll end up with all the GUI text editors you've installed with gedit being among them.

Comment: If you say so...

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies within the body of the question.

In Ubuntu 18.10 gedit was replaced by a Snap package called "Text Editor" to be GNOME's "official" text editor.

AFAIK there is no other option to grab it from the UI.

[image]
[image]